# How to replace a broken knob in my old trailer

Tags: trailer, thread

This knob in an old trailer of mind broke off. Is it possible to replace it?

I'm curious if the aluminum "thread" that inserts into the knob has a name or standard. You can see what I mean in the first picture.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That looks like the same male portion that sticks out of the crank out windows in my house. My knob looks completely different, but I think that's a fairly universal male "thread" and a local hardware store will have something for you.

Comment: That was it thx. Can check mark your answer.

Comment: One item ... Vice Grip. :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be certain that the thread is a standard size. Take the screw or a similar one to a hardware store and they will help you find a matching one.

As was mentioned in the comments, the attachment looks very much like a standard window crank. I would bet that a search on Google or the like would turn up some sources.

Comment: I found the Crank at Miner's

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use Round Valve for plumbing. Something like this and bolt it down really well for a tight fit. To secure the fit, may be even use liquid nails or solder it to the male piece.

[image]